RecyclerView Drag and Drop Scrolling Issue with NestedScrollView in Android
I am working on an Android project where I have a RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView. I have implemented drag and drop functionality using ItemTouchHelper. However, the drag and drop scrolling is not working as expected. When I try to drag an item to the top or bottom of the RecyclerView, it does not scroll automatically.  Here is the relevant part of my layout file:
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Other views -->

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvLocations"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvSavedLocation"
            tools:itemCount="3"
            tools:listitem="@layout/row_search_location_list_item" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

And here is the relevant part of my kotlin file:
val touchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(UP + DOWN, 0) {
    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
        onItemMove(viewHolder.absoluteAdapterPosition, target.absoluteAdapterPosition)
        return true
    }

    override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {
        clearFocusFromAnyOftheChildOfRV()
        return true
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        // No swipe action needed
    }
})

touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.rvStops)

I have tried various solutions, such as setting isNestedScrollingEnabled to false on the RecyclerView, but nothing seems to work. How can I enable drag and drop scrolling for the RecyclerView inside the NestedScrollView?
What I have tried:

Setting isNestedScrollingEnabled to false on the RecyclerView.
Wrapping the RecyclerView in another ViewGroup.

Any help would be appreciated!
